# What happens to classes in Java Program when the program runs?

Tags: java, class, oop, scope, nested

I was reading about Nested classes and especially inner classes where I came across the problem of defining a class inside the scope of for-loop.
What I know so far is that class is a type and we create instances from that type.

As class could be defined once in Java Program, but the code written below looks like `Inner class` is defined again and again in every iteration of `for-loop`. Is it so? If yes then how is it possible? If no then how JVM treats classes, in the case of nested classes and in the case of standalone class

```
class Outer{
    int outer_x = 100;
    
    void test(){
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            class Inner{
                void display(){
                    System.out.println("Display: outer_x = " + outer_x);
                }
            }
            Inner inner = new Inner();
            inner.display();
        }
    }
}

class InnerClassDemo{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        outer.test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inner class definitions are not statements, and are not repeated when placed inside a loop.

Your code is essentially just being rewritten similar to:

```
class Outer{
    int outer_x = 100;

    void test(){
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            Inner inner = new Inner(this);
            inner.display();
        }
    }
}

class Inner{
    final Outer outer;
    Inner(final Outer outer) {
      this.outer = outer;
    }

    void display(){
        System.out.println("Display: outer_x = " + outer.outer_x);
    }
}
```

You can see this in action with `javap`. Here's the Inner class that gets an extra final member, and a constructor with an extra argument:

```
$ javap Outer\$1Inner.class
Compiled from "Foo.java"
class Outer$1Inner {
  final Outer this$0;
  Outer$1Inner(Outer);
  void display();
}
```

Comment: Nice use of the Java dissassembler to prove your answer 1+